# Getting RunTimeException:com.github.fge.jsonschema.cfg.ValidationConfigurationBuilder in fge/jsonSchemaValidator

Tags: java, json, maven

I have used 2.2.5 version of [https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator] using maven dependency

```
<dependency>     
<groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>     
<artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>     
<version>2.2.5</version> 
</dependency>
```

I am trying to validate a simple json against schema given in code samples. When I load the page, I get a runTimeException as:

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.fge.jsonschema.cfg.ValidationConfigurationBuilder
        at com.github.fge.jsonschema.cfg.ValidationConfiguration.newBuilder(ValidationConfiguration.java:92)
        at com.github.fge.jsonschema.cfg.ValidationConfiguration.byDefault(ValidationConfiguration.java:102)
        at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.(JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.java:68)
        at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.newBuilder(JsonSchemaFactory.java:123)
        at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault(JsonSchemaFactory.java:113)

Do I need a version upgrade for any of the jars or is it because of some other issue?

Comment: Are you sure your webapp actually has this dependency on runtime? How do you install it and what app-server do you use?